# Updated_postmeta parameters return nothing

Tags: wordpress

I wanna try hook, an update action of my custom fields. If a particular custom fields is updated,  I wanna to display the date.

In my functions.php :

```
function add_date_war($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)
{   
    echo 'test : ' . $meta_key;
    if($meta_key == 'relics')
    {
        echo date('d-m-Y');
    } 
}
add_action( 'updated_postmeta', 'add_date_war', 10, 4);
```

and on my front_page.php :

```
do_action('updated_postmeta');
```

The function return the echo, but I don't know why $meta_key ( or all others params ) are empty.

If you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do_action also passed parameter which register this hook accept parameters. 
For example:

```
//something insert data into database
$save_meta_id = 1;
$object_id = 5; 
$meta_key = 'meta_key_name';
$meta_value = 'something';
do_action('updated_postmeta', $save_meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
```

Register with action hook accept 4 parametars

```
add_action( 'updated_postmeta', 'add_date_war', 10, 4);
function( $meta_id, $obj_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ){
  echo $meta_id; // 1
  echo $obj_id; // 5
  echo $meta_key; // meta_key_name
  echo $meta_value; // something
}
```